# Checksum Query - 18 Places

Tags: hex, checksum

I am trying to extrapolate what the checksum would be where the exact same change happens in a text string.

The final two digits reduce by 18 places.  Where the last two digits are 19-99 this is really easy to calculate

My issue is when the existing two digits are less than 18

I know in all scenarios the last two digits reduce by 18 places.

Known working examples:

Checksum 33 becomes 15
Checksum 61 becomes 43
Checksum 65 becomes 48

Checksum for 12 becomes 5B
Checksum for 02 becomes 4B

I need to work out what the new checksum would be for 2C and 1E and a wee explanation of how I can then work out any similar sum

I have outlined the examples above

Comment: There are hundreds of checksum algorithms out there. Please [edit] your question with much more detail about exactly what you're talking about, including what your input is.

Comment: I’m not sure what the checksum is. I only know it’s always reduces by 18 places. There is a text string for a module code. In all scenarios an A becomes Q and the last two digits reduce by 18 places as a result.